# Pynput - Постоянное выполнение кода при держании клавиши

Tags: python

У меня возникла проблема при использовании pynput - нашел только что бы при нажатии клавиши срабатывал бинд, но если продолжить держать эту клавишу то код будет выполнятся все время. Как устроить что бы при нажатии клавиши, если пользователь держит ее - то код не будет выполнятся повторно?

```
from pynput import keyboard
COMBINATIONS = [
    {keyboard.KeyCode(char='W')},
    {keyboard.KeyCode(char='w')},
    {keyboard.KeyCode(char='ц')},
    {keyboard.KeyCode(char='Ц')}
]

current = set()

def on_press(key):
        if any([key in COMBO for COMBO in COMBINATIONS]):
            current.add(key)
            if any(all(k in current for k in COMBO) for COMBO in COMBINATIONS):
                pyautogui.press("ctrl")
    with keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
        listener.join()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы обрабатываете действие на опускание клавиши вниз `on_press`, а необходимо обрабатывать отпускание клавиши `on_release`. Также оператор `with`, должен быть за пределами функции.

Comment: Спасибо! Если что "with" все хорошо в коде, тут он немного криво вставился.